# pwd add '\' in folder spaces

Tags: directory, pwd

i know that on Linux when you try to `cd` with folder that have spaces you must add \ in there.

for example, i have folder named `folder one`.

when i try `pwd` the output is :

```
/home/user/folder one
```

what i want is when i try to `pwd` the output is :

```
/home/user/folder\ one
```

how to do that?

Comment: Why would you want to escape the space in the output of `pwd`? What are you using the output for and how?  A more common way to avoid splitting strings in expansions (i.e. variable expansions or command substitutions) is to simply double quote the expansion, i.e., `printf 'The current directory is %s\n' "$(pwd)"`

Comment: @Kusalananda i made neovim shortcut for open folder in current file like this: `!xdg-open $(pwd)`. i got error when i have folder that have spaces in there. btw thank you, now i found a solution in here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52459/is-it-possible-to-have-bash-escape-spaces-in-pwd

Comment: instead of using `xdg-open $(pwd)` i'm using `xdg-open .`

Comment: Use `.` or `"$(pwd)"` (as suggested by @Kusalananda).

Answer (score 0):

I seconded Kusalananda's comment above (well, fifthed) for your specific use case, but to answer your question straight up, when one seeks to use shell quoting when printing values, use `printf`'s `%q` formatting directive:

Try:

```
$ alias mypwd='printf '\''%q\n'\'' "$PWD"'
```

Usage:

```
$ mkdir "/tmp/foo bar"
$ cd "/tmp/foo bar"
$ mypwd
/tmp/foo\ bar
```

Note that this is a feature of the `bash` shell built-in `printf`, and may not be available in `/usr/bin/printf`.